# "someone will have arrived yesterday" - Future Perfect Tense in the past?

Tags: grammar, future-perfect, time-reference

> If they’re following their schedule, they **will have arrived yesterday**.

Yesterday? But yesterday is not a part of the future? I'm confused now.

Comment: I'd say, "If they’re following their schedule, they would have arrived yesterday."

Comment: You may find a similar question here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/488337/the-future-perfect-continuous-prediction-what-was-happening-in-the-past/488346#488346

Answer (score 1):

This is a confusing sentence, but I would interpret the "will" here as meaning "must" rather than literally referring to the future. "They must have arrived yesterday."

Comment: Do you think the sentence is controversial? I don't find it grammatical.

Comment: No, it seems pretty natural. In fact, I'm not sure how else you would express it without subtly changing the connotation. Written this way, it sounds like you are very confident they did arrive yesterday, based on the schedule.

Comment: To elaborate, it's a confusing sentence when you try to think of how it works grammatically (at least for me, not being trained in English language education), but it doesn't *sound* that weird.

Comment: Are you saying the sentence might not be grammatical?

Comment: No, it's grammatical, it's just advanced. See the link SunnySideDown commented on your question - it's a good explanation.

Comment: I just read it. I wonder if this kind of sentence is common in native English speakers' conversations

Comment: Yes, this kind of sentence is common. LIke all modals, _will_ can have an [epistemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality) meaning as well as a [deontic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_modality) one. Its deontic meaning often refers to the future, which is why expressions using _will_ are so often mis-characterised as a "future tense". This is an example which requires an epistemic reading.

Comment: Foreign users similarly get confused over the use of would as denoting a habit or routine occurrence in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt anyone can "will" a traffic delay which is inclined to mean *intent, deliberate, with a mental control*

But a natural consequence, if nothing goes wrong, ought to use "would".

**If they’re following their schedule, they *would* have arrived yesterday.**

Answer (score 0):

*will* here is to be taken in the sense of *then it must surely be the case that*

Their presence upon arrival is the "result in the present" which concerns the speaker most, triggers the construction with *have*, even though *yesterday* would otherwise trigger a simple past tense.

Answer (score 0):

No. No one can arrive yesterday in the future. Will denotes what is in the future. I cannot plan on arriving yesterday. I could have though. I could have arrived yesterday but I cannot arrive yesterday. I can have arrived yesterday.

Comment: That depends on what the author wanted to suggested. While not logically possible, I don't see a problem with it grammatically. Just think of it as a construction from a novel about time travel, and the sentence becomes a lot more reasonable.